# Given error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, null, typeerror, innerhtml

I have an error being displayed in my code.

With this button:

```
 <button style="display:none" id="saveH" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="makeToDoList(); displayTDL();">Save</button>
```

When the button is clicked it suppose to display a div that lists what the user inputs in the "form". However, when I run the code it gives me this error: *1025:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*

[Here is a link to a JSFiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/sprz05/qstdpwez/25/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

suggests that it can't set the `innerHTML` property of an a `null` value. A `null` value is the result of a `getElementById()` query which comes up empty.

So looking at what line the error occurs you can see it can't set the `innerHTML` of the
`result9h` element. And that is because it does not exist in your HTML.